# Restoring a partition with Paragon Backup And Recovery 16: Cannot open/create file

Tags: backup, partition-recovery, paragon

While using [Paragon Backup & Recovery 16](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/brh/) to restore a partition (of about 700Gig) to a new hard drive, it seems to go right up to some random point (between 4% and 6%) and then it stops with the message:

> Cannot open/create file

No extra information is shown whatsoever. Also the event-logs show nothing interesting.

I tried it multiple times and each time it seems to get a little bit farther before throwing the error, until at some point it cannot continue because the destination file-system seems to be corrupt. After formatting the new drive again in Windows, I can start to restore again. But the same story happens, at some point the "Cannot open/create file" pops up again.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it was [Synergy](https://symless.com/synergy/) that was interfering. I use it to share my keyboard and mouse between two machines.

After stopping the Synergy service, the backup was restored in one go without any interruption or error!

To stop the synergy service:

- go to Start -> Run.
- Type in "services.msc" and hit enter.
- Scroll down and select the Synergy service.
- Right-click it and select stop.

I hope this saves someone the headache I went through to find this...